# get_actions() missing 1 required positional argument: 'request'

Tags: python, django, django-admin

Este es mi código (estoy utilizando django 2):

```
def get_actions(self, obj, request):
    actions = super().get_actions(request)
    if 'Emergencia' in obj.nombre:
        actions = ()
    else:
        actions = actions
    return actions
```

o sino se puede hacer así. ¿hay alguna alternativa que pueda hacer para que altere los "actions" según algo diferencia "x" columna?

No sé cual es el fallo, seguramente sea una tontería

Comment: El error no parece estar en la llamada al super() sino en la llamada a tu propio `get_actions()` porque no le estás pasando el tercer parámetro. ¿Cuál es el error completo?, ¿de dónde sale el parámetro `obj `?

Comment: por lo que he visto y comentado no sé puede hacer con un get_actions, porque no te coge el obj

Answer (score 0):

Tu error esta en el super, tu funcion define como parametros self, obj y request, y al llamar a super() que deneria de tener la misma cantidad de parametros te falta incluir obj.

```
def get_actions(self, obj, request):
    actions = super().get_actions(obj, request)
    if 'Emergencia' in obj.nombre:
        actions = ()
    else:
        actions = actions
    return actions
```

Comment: Lamentablemente no, sigue dando el mismo error. Me parecía que ibas a tener razón, también he probado poniendo en el super(NombreClass, self) + lo que decías claro, pero no hay manera